# Python Class with ctypes attributes has side effects

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, mutable

I create a class for an image buffer. The class looks like this:

```
import ctypes

class ImgBuf():
    def __init__(self, bufnr=ctypes.c_int(-1)):
        self.bufnr = bufnr
```

The attribute 'bufnr' is handed over to a shared library by reference and changed for buffer management. I want to have multiple instances of this class (to manage several image buffers). In the small example

```
import imgBuf.ImgBuf
buf1 = dicamsdk.ImgBuf()
buf2 = dicamsdk.ImgBuf()
sharedDLL.allocateBuffer(buf1)
```

the `bufNr` has been changed in the both instances. How can I make instances independent?

Comment: When I try to run that, I get `TypeError: an integer is required (got type c_int)` on the `ctypes.c_int(bufnr)` call. Are you sure this is what you actually ran?

Comment: Indeed there was a type due to from reduction of the code. Corrected that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`ctypes.c_int`, like `list`, is mutable, which should not use as a default argument, a very common mistake. You should create a new object each time the function is called:

```
class ImgBuf():
    def __init__(self, bufnr=None):
        if bufnr is None:
            bufnr = ctypes.c_int(-1)
        self.bufnr =ctypes.c_int(bufnr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Default values for kwargs like `bufnr` will only get evaluated once at load-time, when the `def` statement is read. So in this case, a `c_int` will be created once and the same instance is then used for all `ImgBuf` instances that don't specify `bufnr` explicitly.

To avoid this, you would tyipcally use `None` as the default, then check for `is None` and instantiate the default value if needed inside the function's body, which creates a new instance every time.

The same applies for any other mutable object used as a default value, like lists, dicts and so on. See [this link](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm).

Answer (score -1):

See the following code snipped:

```
from imgBuf import ImgBuf
buf1 = ImgBuf()
buf2 = ImgBuf()
print('id(buf1) == id(buf2): ', id(buf1) == id(buf2))
print('id(buf1.bufnr) == id(buf2.bufnr): ', id(buf1.bufnr) == id(buf2.bufnr))
```

The output is

```
id(buf1) == id(buf2):  False
id(buf1.bufnr) == id(buf2.bufnr):  True
```

Even though python correctly creates two instances of the class object, the ctypes values have the same identity. Usually, this is not a problem as python manages the storage. But this does not apply to the shared library in use.

The default values have been copied to ensure independent instances. The class looks like this:

```
import ctypes
from copy import copy

class ImgBuf():
    def __init__(self, bufnr=ctypes.c_int(-1)):
        self.bufnr = copy(ctypes.c_int(bufnr))
```

Now the objects should be independent (run code snipped again).